# How do I convert an id to a username? discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need the convert a players id stored in a database and convert it to their username to be displayed on a leaderboard. How would I go about doing this? I'm on discord.js v12.

I've tried this:

```
fetchuser = message.guild.members.fetch(userid)
fetchuser = fetchuser.username
```

Comment: Never say "most methods I've tried didn't work". You will most likely get answers of those same methods that didn't work, because often, there is exactly one or two ways to do something like this. It is a waste of both the asker and answerer's time. Instead, show the methods you've tried, at least one of them, and ask why it's not working. Then you will get an exact answer (such as, this is outdated, use this instead - or you wrote this part wrong, move this here - etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const User = client.users.cache.get("UserID"); // Getting the user by ID.
if (User) { // Checking if the user exists.
    message.channel.send(User.tag) // The user exists.
} else {
    message.channel.send("User not found.") // The user doesn't exists or the bot couldn't find him.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to fetch the user with that ID. Then, manually construct their tag

Assuming your "id" is stored in the variable `id` and "client" is your bot.

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch(id, { cache: true });
const userTag = `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`;
```

Comment: This looks promising, but returns ```undefined```. Can you help out with this if you have the time?

Comment: Please send the code you're using right now.

Comment: (code for the command / where you are fetching the user)