# Convert discord username (User#0001) to a discord ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can you do this? I have an online form with discord usernames and want to convert them to user IDs.

Couldn't find anything online that does this. Would the most efficient way be add the user, copy id ?

Or is there a simpler soultion. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an id to a username? discord.js v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543408/how-do-i-convert-an-id-to-a-username-discord-js-v12)

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to do this **directly** through an endpoint on the API, [and they don't plan to add it as per this issue on their devrel repo](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1574).

If all of your users are in a guild of yours though, you can add a bot to it and pass each username to the [Search Guild Members](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#search-guild-members) endpoint. This will return you a list of [Guild Member Objects](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object) matching the username, which will have the user ID.

Comment: Will this work if the user has a funky name including spaces, special characters, etc? (assuming they type their username correctly?)

Comment: It should! But remember to [URL Encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) the query correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using discord.js (since the tag is included)

Fetch all the guild members, then use `.find()` to get a specific member by their `.tag`

```js
const tags = ["User#0001", ...];
const members = await <Guild>.members.fetch();

const ids = tags.map(tag => members.find(memer => member.tag === tag));
```

Comment: Will this work if the user has a funky name including spaces, special characters, etc? (assuming they type their username correctly?)

Comment: Aslong as the characters can be represented in a string, yes. You'll have to test specific cases yourself